# Mapping delimited text field to taxonomy field in Migrate

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I have a migration from an external (non-Drupal) DB which is currently working correctly. I am trying to add a field from the external DB which contains a delimited list of terms.

I have set up the field mapping as follows:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_test_structure_families', 'proteinfamilyname')
     ->separator('@');

$this->addFieldMapping('field_test_structure_families:create_term')
     ->defaultValue(TRUE);

$this->addFieldMapping('field_test_structure_families:ignore_case')
     ->defaultValue(TRUE);
```

I want to dynamically add these terms to the taxonomy specified on the field_test_structure_families field - from the documentation that should be what is happening with this config. There is no pre-existing term vocabulary in the external DB.

When I run the migration and try to update existing nodes, nothing is added to the field or the specified vocabulary. The target field is set as an autocomplete field. I have tried with checkbox/radio setting with the same outcome.

Where am I going wrong? Is it that this won't work with pre-existing nodes? Any help welcome.